# How do I get the proper context for my constructor AlertDialog.Builder?

Tags: java, android

I want to use  `AlertDialog.Builder` inside a method, which will be called by an `Activity`, problem is, this method is defined inside a `Service`, so this and `Activity`.this etc doesn't appear to be working, here is the abridged code:

```
public class BluetoothLeService extends Service {
...
    public void setCharacteristicNotification(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, boolean enabled) 
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CONTEXT);
            builder.setMessage("Write the CCCD Descriptor?").setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener)
                .setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener).show();

    }
}
```

This method you saw above will be called in:

```
public  class DeviceControlActivity extends Activity {

    private final BroadcastReceiver mGattUpdateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
              ...
                if ((UserValueCharacteristic.PROPERTY_NOTIFY) > 0) {
                          mNotifyCharacteristic = UserValueCharacteristic;
                          mBluetoothLeService.setCharacteristicNotification(
                          UserValueCharacteristic, true);
               }

           }
      }
```

}

Now I don't know what is the proper context to get, least how to get them.

With a little research I decided that `AlertDialog.Builder` will only take activity `Context`, and the most likely `Activity` `Context` it should get belongs to `DeviceControlActivity`, and I've tried:

```
this (return unable to add window token null error during run time)

DeviceControlActivity.this (won't compile, saying class is non-closing)

DeviceControlActivity.getapplication()

DeviceControlActivity.getapplication().this
```

and so far none of them worked.

This starts to feel like a design flaw of android API, this is really unreasonable. A popup message shouldn't be such a hassle.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Add a class which extends Application class and in its onCreate Method instantiate the object of that class. Now in your service get the context like this MyApplicationClass.getInstance().getApplicationContext();

Answer (score 0):

> so this and activity.this etc doesn't appear to be working

[Service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) extends [Context](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) so it should not be a issue. Maybe the problem you are facing is not related to the AlertDialog.Builder.

You can try as well :

```
public class BluetoothLeService extends Service {
...
    public void setCharacteristicNotification(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, boolean enabled) 
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
            builder.setMessage("Write the CCCD Descriptor?").setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener)
                .setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener).show();

    }
}
```

Edit :

Use the context give by the broadcast receiver

```
public class BluetoothLeService extends Service {
...
    public void setCharacteristicNotification(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, boolean enabled, Context context) 
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            builder.setMessage("Write the CCCD Descriptor?").setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener)
                .setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener).show();

    }
}


public  class DeviceControlActivity extends Activity {

    private final BroadcastReceiver mGattUpdateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
              ...
                if ((UserValueCharacteristic.PROPERTY_NOTIFY) > 0) {
                          mNotifyCharacteristic = UserValueCharacteristic;
                          mBluetoothLeService.setCharacteristicNotification(
                          UserValueCharacteristic, true, context);
               }

           }
      }
```

Comment: hello, getApplicationContext tried before, no joy :( @Cochi

Comment: hello, I tried that, bad token exception as mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you need to do is to pass the context to the method. Here is an example how:

```
public void setCharacteristicNotification(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, boolean enabled, Context context) 
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setMessage("Write the CCCD Descriptor?").setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener)
            .setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener).show();

}
```

and when you call the method from the activity just pass the activity context

```
if ((UserValueCharacteristic.PROPERTY_NOTIFY) > 0) {
                      mNotifyCharacteristic = UserValueCharacteristic;
                      mBluetoothLeService.setCharacteristicNotification(
                      UserValueCharacteristic, true, myActivity.Context);
}
```

Comment: Hello @Ricardo, I put in context it appears to be fine, but following your advice I put in this and it hinted error: Wrong argument type. Found:'android.content.BroadcastReceiver', required:'android.content.context'

Comment: and when using context, I got bad exception error again, as mentioned in the question.

Comment: Hello, there must be a delay in SO, the error is:error: Wrong argument type. Found:'android.content.BroadcastReceiver', required:'android.content.context'

Comment: Try defining as global variable `Context context`, inside onCreate write `context = this;` then call `mBluetoothLeService.setCharacteristicNotification(
                      UserValueCharacteristic, true, context);`

Comment: hello, the activity does not have an onCreate method called inside it, can I add it arbitrarily?

Comment: Yes you can, it's an Activity, just override the method

Comment: Hello again, same exception as always. Something is terribly wrong somewhere. I decleared a public static variable of Context type and give this to it in onCreate, doesn't work.

Comment: Glad it helped :) I changed my answer in case you decide to mark it as correct

Comment: I called the myActivity.Context directly since it's global anyway, you might wanna update that  :)